# How to get simpler but equivalent version of a Haskell expression

Tags: haskell

Although I have been learning Haskell for some time, there is one common problem I run into constantly. Let's take this expression as an example:

```
e f $ g . h i . j
```

One may wonder, given `$` and `.` from Prelude, what are type constraints on `e` or `h` for expression to be valid?

Is it possible to get a 'simpler' but equivalent representation? For me, 'simpler' would be one that uses parentheses everywhere and eliminates need to define operator precedence rules.

If not, which Haskell report sections do I need to read to have complete picture?

This might be relevant for many novice Haskell programmers. I know many programmers that add parentheses so that they do not need to memorize (or understand) precedence tables like this one: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: `e f (\x -> g (h i (j x)))`? I'm not sure what you're after. You don't need to memorise precendence tables, you can just ask GHCi. `:info (.)` tells you `infixr 9 .`, while `:info ($)` tells you `infixr 0 $`.

Comment: @kqr I think he's looking for a way to quickly turn `e f $ g . h i . j` into `(e f) $ (g . ((h i) . j))`

Comment: You also need to be aware of other rules that are in place. For example function application precedence and infix operator precedence like in `f g . h`. Are there more rules? I am looking for a way to apply all those rules and see the parse result.

Comment: @Peter Yes, that's what I'm after. Thanks for showing how this example looks like after being transformed.

Comment: @Rumca Function application binds tighter than everything except for parentheses.

Comment: @kqr Yes, but you need to learn first that `.` is not being applied to `g` in `f g . h` unless in parentheses. I do not want to sound picky here. I am just pointing out stuff that novice must learn first before they understand how Haskell expressions work.

Comment: Sure. All-character identifiers are operators, is the missing piece of information there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible to get a 'simpler' but equivalent representation? Of course, this is called parsing, and is done by compilers, interpreters, etc.

90% of the time, all you need to remember is how `$` , `.` and function application `f x` work together. This is because `$` and function application are really simple - they bind the loosest and tightest respectively - they are like addition and the exponent in [bodmas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BODMAS#Mnemonics).

From your example

```
e f $ g . h i . j
```

the function applications bind first, so we have

```
(e f) $ g . (h i) . j
```

Function application is left associative so

```
f g h ==> ((f g) h)
```

You may have to google currying to understand why the above can be used like `foo(a, b)` in other languages.

In the next step do everything in the middle - I just use brackets or a table to remember this bit, it's usually straightforward. For example there are several operators like `>>` and `>>=` that are used at the same time when you are working with monads. I just add brackets when ghc complains.

So no we have

```
(e f) $ (g . ((h i) . j))
```

The order of the brackets doesn't matter as [function composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition) is associative, however Haskell makes it right associative.

So then we have

```
((e f) (g . ((h i) . j)))
```

The above (simple) example demonstrates why those operators exist in the first place.